# How to get non www to redirect to www?

Tags: dns, vercel

I currently have a domain https://beamanalytics.io but it always goes to https://beamanalytics.io and now https://www.beamanalytics.io. I heard having www as a subdomain does better for SEO. Can someone help me make it such that users that go to https://beamanalytics.io gets redirected to the www one?

I'm out of my wits here. I'm currently using NextJS and Vercel and they took care of all the initial domain setup.

Answer (score 0):

You must add both primary and `www` domains into your project in Vercel. Then, you can set up redirects via project `Settings > Domains`.

There're more details in this [Doc](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/domains/deploying-and-redirecting). Hope this helps.